# Python + BeautifulSoup Exporting to CSV

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I'm having a bit of trouble automatically scraping data in a table from a Wikipedia article. First I was getting an encoding error. I specified UTF-8 and the error went away, but the scraped data doesn't display a lot of the characters correctly. You will be able to tell from the code that I am a complete newbie:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

wiki = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson_Silva"
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'} #Needed to prevent 403 error on Wikipedia
req = urllib2.Request(wiki,headers=header)
page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

Result = ""
Record = ""
Opponent = ""
Method = ""
Event = ""
Date = ""
Round = ""
Time = ""
Location = ""
Notes = ""

table = soup.find("table", { "class" : "wikitable sortable" })

f = open('output.csv', 'w')

for row in table.findAll("tr"):
    cells = row.findAll("td")
    #For each "tr", assign each "td" to a variable.
    if len(cells) == 10:
        Result = cells[0].find(text=True)
        Record = cells[1].find(text=True)
        Opponent = cells[2].find(text=True)
        Method = cells[3].find(text=True)
        Event = cells[4].find(text=True)
        Date = cells[5].find(text=True)
        Round = cells[6].find(text=True)
        Time = cells[7].find(text=True)
        Location = cells[8].find(text=True)
        Notes = cells[9].find(text=True)

        write_to_file = Result + "," + Record + "," + Opponent + "," + Method + "," + Event + "," + Date + "," + Round + "," + Time + "," + Location + "\n"
        write_to_unicode = write_to_file.encode('utf-8')
        print write_to_unicode
        f.write(write_to_unicode)

f.close()
```

Comment: Have you tried using the CSV module (http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)? It handles quoting, etc. That documentation also points you in the right direction for writing out text of different encodings. For your particular problem, though...what isn't displaying correctly with UTF-8? According to the meta tag on that page, the charset is UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

As pswaminathan pointed out, using the `csv` module will help greatly. Here is how I do it:

```
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'wikitable sortable'})
with open('out2.csv', 'w') as f:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(f)
    for row in table.findAll('tr'):
        cells = [c.text.encode('utf-8') for c in row.findAll('td')]
        if len(cells) == 10: 
            csvwriter.writerow(cells)
```

## Discussion

- Using the csv module, I created a `csvwriter` object connected to my output file.
- By using the `with` command, I don't need to worry about closing the output file after done: it will be closed after the with block.
- In my code, `cells` is a list of UTF8-encoded text extracted from the `td` tags within a `tr` tag.
- I used the construct `c.text`, which is more concise than `c.find(text=True)`.